# dates in between two days

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get all the movie ids and names for a given date range. e.g. 2012-02-01 to 2012-02-20 should show ids( 1, 2 and 3) its like now showing movies on a given date range.

```
 movie{ id, name, start_date, end_date, visibility}

id   name  start_date  end_date     visibility
1    abc   2012-01-05   2012-02-10      1
2    xyz   2012-02-05   2012-02-25      1
3    cde   2012-02-19   2012-02-27      1
4    ghi   2012-03-01   2012-03-20      1
```

Comment: Are you going to compare start_date or the end_date of the movie with the date interval?

Comment: There are more than 4 ways that the question can be interpreted. Cn you clarify what you want the query to test?

Comment: Google 'Allen's interval comparison operators'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select id, name from `movie` where 
end_date >= '2012-01-05' and 
start_date <= '2012-01-20'
```

This works for me and its looks simple.

Answer (score 2):

Guessing that you want to find the overlap, assuming the parameter values are in a table named `params`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM movie AS m, params AS p
 WHERE CASE 
          WHEN m.start_date > p.start_date THEN m.start_date 
          ELSE p.start_date 
       END
       <
       CASE 
          WHEN m.end_date > p.end_date THEN p.end_date 
          ELSE m.end_date 
       END;
```

Comment: Isn't the `WHERE m.start_date <= p.end_date AND p.start_date <= m.end_date` equivalent?

Comment: @ypercube: hint: what if you wanted to show the overlap in the results?

Comment: Cool, I hadn't thought of that!

Answer (score 2):

We have two intervals:

the `FieldInterval  :=  (start_date, end_date)`

and the `TestInterval := (@StartDate, @EndDate)`, defined as

```
@StartDate = '2012-02-01' 
@EndDate = '2012-02-20'
```

---

To test if `FieldInterval`is inside `TestInterval`:

```
SELECT id 
FROM movie 
WHERE @StartDate <= start_date      
  AND end_date <= @EndDate
```

---

To test if `TestInterval` is inside `FieldInterval`:

```
SELECT id 
FROM movie 
WHERE start_date <= @StartDate  
  AND @EndDate <= end_date
```

---

To test if the two intervals overlap:

```
SELECT id 
FROM movie 
WHERE start_date <= @EndDate 
  AND @StartDate <= end_date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id  from movie  
where start_date between '2012-02-01' and '2012-02-20' 
and end_date between '2012-02-01' and '2012-02-20'
and start_date <= end_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want movies which start_date and end_date fit into 2 parameters, right?

```
select id, name from movie
where @startDate < create_date and end_date< @endDate
```

If you inform 2012-02-01 and 2012-02-20 it will return all the movies which have start_date and end_date between that range